# Does anyone know how to solve this problem,After i upgraded big sur

Tags: macos

When I type ls in the terminal prompt:

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:311:in `to_specs': Could not find 'clocale' (~> 0) among 52 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem with `ls` after the upgrade to Big Sur, which I traced to `colorls`. You can fix that with the following command:

`sudo gem install colorls`.

If your issue is a little more complicated, as mine was, then following this answer could solve the issue:

[Macos Catalina error after update: unable to run colorls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58303940/macos-catalina-error-after-update-unable-to-run-colorls)

It worked for me.

*Note: I would have asked for clarification in the comments, but I don't have the reputation for that...